# Start new page with each section

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

I would like to start each section on a new page. Is adding the following to my preamble this the preferred method, or a hack?

```
\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\newpage\stdsection}
```

Comment: Perhaps you would like to use `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage` if you use floats.

Comment: Why not use a document class that allows chapters, and use them instead (since they automatically start on new page..)

Comment: @Stefan you are correct, although my present document is not using floats.

Comment: ASeamus not a bad idea, but I'd prefer not to have to change the document class

Comment: Alternatively, just find and replace all `\section{` with `\clearpage\section{`

Comment: @Seamus I'd like to use this in emacs org-mode, so it is more straightforward to place this in the preamble

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With an uptodate TeX distribution you can use

```latex
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\clearpage}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\clearpage}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
Text
\section{Title}
Text
\subsection{Title}
Text
\subsection{Title}
Text
\section{Title}
Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks - I've made this the accepted answer since it is the simplest and doesn't require another package

Comment: How can I learn about the ```\AddToHook{}{}``` command?

Comment: @youthdoo See http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/lthooks-doc.pdf or use `texdoc lthooks-doc` in a command prompt.

Answer (score 115):

The [titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package allows to do this with just

```
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
```

It's cleaner than what you were doing and the package also allows to completely customize sections. Here's a fully compilable code sample showing how it works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

\begin{document}

Text

\section{Title}
Text
\subsection{Title}
Text
\subsection{Title}
Text

\section{Title}
Text

\end{document}
```

Comment: note: if you have a `\subsection` without content, the `\section` after it won't be pushed to a new page. I don't know whether this is a bug, expected, or irrelevant, but I thought it's worth mentioning it as first I was a bit puzzled why the `\clearpage` solution didn't work.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: if you look up the code for `\ttl@straight@ii` in `titlesec.sty`, you clearly see the explanation for this phenomenon: the `\sectionbreak` command is only used if the boolean `@nobreak` is false, which is not the case just after a subsection title (but is once some text has been typesetted). One could easily patch `\ttl@straight@ii` to behave as you want, but it's probably simpler to use the solution from http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47047

Comment: Thanks, this works also great with `\thispagestyle{plain}` together with `\pagestyle{fancyplain}` from the _fancyhdr_ package.

Comment: This seems to be move all pictures to a separate page that I have in my document with \begin{figure}. Is this intended?

Comment: @Kaspar: yes, that's what `\clearpage` does (it clears all figures then makes a page break). Try using another pagebreaking command like `\pagebreak` if you don't want this.

Comment: This solution causes problems when the document includes a ToC and hyperref support: It makes the paging of the hyperref links be off-sync with the document paging (e.g. clicking on Section 3 which is on p4 will take you to p3 instead). In this sense, the hack in the original question is the better approach...

Comment: @landroni: no, it works perfectly. You're probably loading `hyperref` before `titlesec`, which is why it doesn't work (there are a few exceptions, but generally speaking, `hyperref` should be the last package you load). Alternatively, you can make if work with `hyperref` loaded first by using `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage\phantomsection}`.

Comment: Thank you. The latter works indeed in LyX. I've now added an [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section/338738#338738) that also shows an alternative way to make sure that the packages are loaded in the correct order.

Comment: This seems to leave one blank page if your document starts with a new section. Is there a way to account for other than manually telling Tex not to clear that first page?

Comment: @Jim: I don't see that happening in the above code when commenting the first "Text". Maybe something else is interfering? Alternatively, you could always try something like `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\ifnum\value{page}=1\ifnum\value{section}=1\else\clearpage\fi\else\clearpage\fi}`

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet It turned out I had some text before my first `\section` and that made the first `\section` to use `\clearpage` right after that text. Which makes sense.
However, things don't work out for me in general, because apparently `titlesec` doesn't go well with the documentclass `amsart` which I need. Thanks anyway, I liked your approach.

Answer (score 13):

Obligatory ConTeXt solution:

```
\setuphead[section][page=yes] % or page=right
```

Comment: This mysterious answer seems to have more than what meet the eyes. Care to elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @DrBeco: ConTeXt is a macro package built on TeX (just as LaTeX is a macro package built on TeX). ConTeXt has a much more consistent user interface and many questions that arise in LaTeX have a simple solution in ConTeXt. I am one of the few ConTeXt users on this site. And when I wrote this answer, I was proving ConTeXt solution to various LaTeX questions.

Comment: If tex4ht would work with context, I would try context. But from what I understand tex4ht only works with latex. This is a major limitation to many who want to convert latex to HTML as well to pdf.

Comment: ConTeXt supports XHTML and XML export out of the box: https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Export

Answer (score 8):

The [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section#comment829734_9505) in that form won't work as expected in LyX. This solution causes problems when the document includes a `ToC` and `hyperref` support: It makes the paging of the `hyperref` links be off-sync with the document paging (e.g. clicking on Section 3 which is on p4 will take you to p3 instead).

As mentioned in the comments, this happens because by default LyX is loading `hyperref` before `titlesec`. To work around this you can use `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage\phantomsection}`.

Alternatively, in LyX, you can include in `Document Settings > Local Layout`:

```
Provides hyperref
```

And then load `hyperref` manually in the LaTeX preamble, like this:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: +1 for the discussion on LyX. The wider TeX-universe is very diverse, so all aspects are quite valuable to one or the other.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution, which uses the `sectsty` package:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\clearpage}
```

Comment: Thanks, this finally worked. Tre previous answers, including the accepted answer, didn't do the job in overleaf

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution is to enclose each section in an \include, because \include does an automatic \clearpage before. No preamble necessary!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  While this works, it may require quite a substantial change to the set-up of the document.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use what **Philippe Goutet** has already mentioned.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
```

These are very convenient and save you the effort of typing `\clearpage` at the end of each section. Needless to mentioned that you can apply the same to `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`. You can also manage the spacing between the section title and the first paragraph.

Perhaps you should take a look at the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)
if you're interested.

Comment: Would you add this information to the answer above? When answers don't add new information, they may be downvoted on this site.

Comment: So should I delete my answer?

Comment: Yes, I think that the basis of your question doesn't add anything. If there is something new, you can add that as an edit. Brevity is good, few answers (if new answers don't add information) are good for stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

I used to use the `\renewcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}` solution, but it stopped working when I wanted to change the font color using secsty...

so had to use this instead:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\section}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0 \else\clearpage\fi
}
```

the conditional is there to keep it from putting the first section of a new chapter on a new page.
If you want also the first section of each chapter on a new page you can simply use

`\preto{\section}{\clearpage}` with etoolbox or `\sectionfont{\clearpage}` with secsty

Answer (score 1):

For me, only a combination of the previous answers works correctly:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\clearpage\phantomsection}
```

(The same without `\phantomsection` causes refs point to incorrect page.
And `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}` causes an error with pandoc,
with or without `\phantomsection`.)