# How to make \section start automatically in new page, except first in a chapter

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, conditionals

I am working in `report` class. I would like to redefine `\section` so that it starts on a new page, except for the first section in every chapter.

It seems I should just put code from this answer [Start new page with each section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section) together with some conditional like `\if not firstsection then...` but I do not know how to do that properly.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using the `etoolbox` package and a conditional :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pretocmd{\section}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0 \else\clearpage\fi
}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\section{Section One Three}

\end{document}
```

Comment: might you want `\clearpage` instead?

Comment: @cmhughes: yes, if floats are involved, it could be safer; thanks.

Comment: `\preto` is simpler