# Using \clearpage breaks \hyperref bookmarks

Tags: hyperref

From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section) I have used

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
```

to ensure that sections start on their own page. However when using the `hyperref` package this results in the section bookmarks pointing to the end of the previous section instead of the start of the new one.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref} % Generate PDF links and bookmarks.
\hypersetup{
  bookmarks=true,
  bookmarksnumbered=true
}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\section{First}
Some text

\section{Second}
More Text

\end{document}
```

If you use Adobe Reader or Preview on OSX and use the bookmarks you will notice that the second bookmark will be on the first page at the end of the previous section and not on the second page where the second section starts.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch the load order of [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec):

```
\usepackage{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
```

From the [`hyperref` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html) (section **2 Implicit behavior**):

> This package can be used with more or less any normal LaTeX document by specifying in the document preamble
>
> ```
> \usepackage{hyperref}
> ```
>
> Make sure it comes last of your loaded packages, to give it a fighting chance of not being over-written, since its job is to redefine many LaTeX commands.

Packages that can be loaded after is given in [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764)

Answer (score 11):

`\sectionbreak` gets executed at a wrong time after the anchor for the section
(by `\refstepcounter`) is set. The `\clearpage` can also be added by redefining
`\section`. This way `\clearpage` is the very first that is executed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Generate PDF links and bookmarks.        
\hypersetup{         
  bookmarksnumbered=true
}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand*{\OrgSection}{}
\let\OrgSection\section
\renewcommand*{\section}{\clearpage\OrgSection}

\begin{document}
\section{First} 
Some text

\section{Second}
More Text

\end{document}
```

Remarks:

- Option `bookmarks` cannot only be set as package option in `\usepackage`. Otherwise
  you get the warning:

  > Package hyperref Warning: Option `bookmarks' has already been used,
  >   (hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 6.
- You can omit option `pdftex`. Package `hyperref` automatically sets the driver options that it is able to detect (pdfTeX/LuaTeX in PDF mode, XeTeX).
- I recommend package `bookmark`, then you do not need two LaTeX runs to get updated
  bookmarks here.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what I would have to do with the `bookmark` package?