# Wrong anchors in bookmarks and TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdftex, bookmarks

I am having some trouble with some anchors for sections, which automatically start at a new page. The TOC shows the right page numbers, where the PDF bookmarks show the page number of the previous page, which is also used by the anchor referenced by both.

Putting a `\clearpage` just before `\section` would solve the problem and defeat the purpose of using LaTeX for layouting.

My LaTeX preamble starts with

```
\documentclass[fleqn,titlepage=firstiscover,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
...
```

loading and defining some more math and formatting stuff later.

Is there an adaptable solution to this problem? I really do not want to put `\clearpage` where it does not belong.

Comment: have you run latex enough times for the page numbers to stabalize? with an unusable fragment it is very hard to suggest how to change your code, you should probably try to make a small complete document that you can add that shows the problem.

Comment: The build is stable. I'm running latex hundreds of times a day. I'll see, if I can make a small example document tomorrow, after beeing finished with the contents.

Comment: It would be even more interesting how your preamble and your document ends ;-)

Comment: Try loading `bookmark` after `hyperref` package. Does it work?

Comment: `bookmark` wasn't the problem. While writing a short example, I discovered a solution. It was a problem with `hyperref` after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reducing the preamble, I found it working suddenly. After having a look around again, I found [Using \clearpage breaks \hyperref bookmarks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66016/using-clearpage-breaks-hyperref-bookmarks/66017#66017) stating

> This package can be used with more or less any normal LaTeX document by specifying in the document preamble
>
> ```
> \usepackage{hyperref}
> ```
>
> Make sure it comes last of your loaded packages, to give it a fighting chance of not being over-written, since its job is to redefine many LaTeX commands.

from the [`hyperref` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html). So I put `\usepackage{hyperref}` as far at the end of the preamble as possible and everything worked fine. `titlesec` might have been causing my issue as well.

Comment: `titlesec` will break internal features of KOMA-script as well. Since version 3.15, KOMA has a very own interface of defining sectioning commands.