# \addtokomafont{section}{\clearpage} breaks hyperref bookmarks

Tags: sectioning, hyperref

My question is similar to [Using \clearpage breaks \hyperref bookmarks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66016/using-clearpage-breaks-hyperref-bookmarks?newreg=c49865bb2ec449dd87c1b38f3c882eef); I have the same problem using KomaScript: I use `\addtokomafont{section}{\clearpage}` to make sections start on a new page.

When using the hyperref package, the section bookmarks point to the end of the previous section instead of the start of the new one.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered=true}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\addtokomafont{section}{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\section{First}
Some text    
\section{Second}
More Text    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Maybe `\phantomsection` would help.

Comment: ... `\addtokomafont{section}{\clearpage\phantomsection}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered=true}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\let\Section\section
\renewcommand\section{\clearpage\Section}

\begin{document}
    \section{First}
    Some text    
    \section{Second}
    More Text    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution works as well, like `\addtokomafont{section}{\clearpage\phantomsection}`. Which one is the better approach?

Comment: you should use `\addkomafont` only for _ font_ setting and not for anything else ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\addtokomafont{section}{\clearpage\phantomsection}` instead. The `\phantomsection` command is nessesary for [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en) to get correct bookmarks/pages.

So your code gets:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered=true}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\addtokomafont{section}{\clearpage\phantomsection}

\begin{document}
\section{First}
Some text    
\section{Second}
More Text    
\end{document}
```