# How to have titlesec-like behaviour in KOMA-Script?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, titlesec

I am using `\documentclass{scrartcl}` which I believe is a KOMA-Script type.

I now wish to have each `\section{}` start in a new page, similar to what `\usepackage{titlesec}` offers, as shown on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section).

How can I do so?

Currently, I get this warning which is why I asked this question:

```
Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of package `titlesec' together
(scrartcl) with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended. 
(scrartcl) I'd suggest to use the package only 
(scrartcl) if you really need it, because it breaks several
(scrartcl) KOMA-Script features, i.e., option `headings' and
(scrartcl) the extended optional argument of the section
(scrartcl) commands .
(scrartcl) Nevertheless, using requested
(scrartcl) package `titlesec' on input line 7.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! So your real question is how to have new sections always start on a new page with KOMA-Script?

Comment: @cgnieder Hello, yes that's right! :)

Comment: One way: load the package `etoolbox` and add `\preto\section{\clearpage}` to the preamble

Comment: @cgnieder That worked! Please post that as the answer and I will mark it as correct. I could answer my own question with this but you deserve the credit!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a `\clearpage` to each section:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\addtokomafont{section}{\clearpage}
\begin{document}

\section{foo}foo
\section{bar}bar
\subsection{foooo} foooo
\section{baz}baz
\section{foobar}foobar

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I wanted to reduce the white space below a section header? `\addtokomafont{element }{command}` seems to execute whatever instructions `command` contains before printing the section title.

Comment: Use `\ReDeclareSectionCommand`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. `\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=<length>,beforeskip=<length>]{section}` worked great.

Answer (score 2):

All credit goes to [cgnieder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/cgnieder) for this solution.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\preto\section{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two Should Start On Another Page}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Herbert's solution is for all intents an purposes identical to this, except that it uses the built-in KOMA hook for modifying the section code (and so is probably to be preferred; it also doesn't require an extra package). There is nothing added each time you make a new section with his code either.

Comment: @AlanMunn I think it got edited, previously I was under the impression that we had to manually add `\clearpage` after every section.

Comment: @Herbert's solution is better for at least one reason: the KOMA font “section” is also used by `\addsec` so the addition works for it, too. With `etoolbox` you'd need to patch it, too.