# Issue with page breaks before section and toc hyperlinks

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, page-breaking

I need page breaks before each `\section{...}` of my document. According to this thread: [Start new page with each section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section) I am supposed to add following command:

```
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage} % page break before section
```

There is a problem using `toc` with `hyperref` though. Hyperlinks from `toc` to each section are set one page prior their actual page position. In the following example:

- If in `toc` I click on hyperlink of **Section 1** (which is on **page
  2**), I will stay on **page 1**.
- If in `toc` I click on hyperlink of **Section 2** (which is on **page
  3**), I will be carried to **page 2**.

Here is a ready to test code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl} % A4 paper and 12pt font size

\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks
\usepackage{titlesec} % customizing sections

\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage} % page break before section

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
Text
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
Text
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
Text

\section{Section 2}
Text
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
Text
\subsection{Subsection 2.2}
Text
Text

\end{document}
```

I need either a fix for the wrong linkage in `toc` or some other method of inserting page breaks before sections, which is compatible with `toc` hyperlinks.

Comment: Try `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage\phantomsection}` ?

Comment: Switch the loading order of [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). You need to load `hyperref` *after* `titlesec` (see [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764)). Also [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) suggests avoid `titlesec` to modify the sectional units.

Comment: @MikeRenfro thanks, your solution almost worked for me, I still had some positioning problems (not pagewise though). Werner described the core of the problem.

Comment: @Werner Thanks a lot for elaborating, I switched `hyperref` and `titlesec`; hyperlinks started working as expected. Due to your hint on `titlesec`, I am going to extract sections to own .tex files and include them into the main .tex, so I am no longer in need of `titlesec`. I would accept your answer as correct if it would not be a plain answer to my question. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Note that Mike Renfro's code does away with the need for `titlesec` while allowing you to keep everything in one file, should you wish to do so.

Comment: @cfr switching `hyperref` and `titlesec`, without modfiing the `sectionbreak` part, would as well allow me to keep everything in one file. Adding a `phantomsection` was not a solution, but a workaround, which builed on a broken order of package imports. Beside that, I still had some positioning problems on some other subsections, which was still a problem of wrong order of imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) manipulate important, *related* elements of a document. As such, loading order should always be considered. In this case, the loading order should resemble

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
...
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

as implicitly suggested by [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764). However, you'll also find [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) mention the following in the `.log` about loading `titlesec`:

```
Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of package `titlesec' together
(scrartcl)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrartcl)              I'd suggest to use the package only
(scrartcl)              if you really need it, because it breaks several
(scrartcl)              KOMA-Script features, i.e., option `headings' and
(scrartcl)              the extended optional argument of the section
(scrartcl)              commands .
(scrartcl)              Nevertheless, using requested
(scrartcl)              package `titlesec' on input line 4.
```

While packages are meant to extend certain "restrictions" imposed by a document class, flexible classes (like `memoir`) which provide their own functionality should be considered.