# Wrong section number with fancyhdr when using clearpage

Tags: fancyhdr, titlesec

I am using Latex for my Bachelors Thesis and I have run into a little problem, I haven't been able to fix yet:

I am using Article as my document class and want each section to start with a new page, so I used

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
```

as is suggested here: [Start new page with each section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section)

This does however seem to confuse fancyhdr, which I use to print the Section-Number in the Footer of on each page.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Title of the Thesis}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\thesection}
```

Because now every time a Section ends, if there was room for anything from that section on the page, it puts the section number of the following section into the footer. So for example the last page of Section 1 has  Section 2 in the footer.

Is there anything I can do to fix this, or should I rather switch to a different document class, which has new page on each Chapter/Section per default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the mark mechanism to print the section number in header or footer

```
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{\thesection}{}}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
```

Example:
    \documentclass[twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Title of the Thesis}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}

\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{Section~\thesection}{}}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\leftmark}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if almost every section should start on a new page I would use a report class with chapters.

Comment: Thanks. Both approaches (using mark mechanism and switching to report class) worked