# New \section on new page

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

Is there a way to add something to document-header, in order to automatically insert a `\newpage` before each `\section` I write?

2nd Edit: In fact, I already know the question [Start new page with each section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section) and its related answers. But it did not helped me. Please let me explain why: In fact, when adding

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
```

to document-header, this will break all the big Titles, including the one of the table of contents. So, again: How to kind-of automatically add a `\newpage` before all the `\section`, and only before those?

Comment: BTW: `\newline` would not start a new page.

Comment: Is `\newline` a typo? Did you mean to write `\newpage`? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I meant that. Thank you, I just edited it.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows us your problems when trying the linked solution?