# How to turn on/off \newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage} per chapter?

Tags: sectioning, clearpage

I have a book with lots of chapters and many sections in each chapter.

Some chapters, I want to automatically make each section start on new page, but not in some other chapters.

The problem is that `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}` from `titlesec` when added to preamble, has a global effect on the whole document. So all sections in each chapter will start on new page.

Is there a way to control when this command is active (or other solution) so one can turn it on/off at start of the chapter they want each section to start on or not at a new page?

I can of course not use  `titlesec` command at all, and manually add `\clearpage` before each `section` in those specific chapters, but this is too much work, as there are many sections and many chapters, and also if later I changed my mind, I have to go edit them all again one by one.

If there is one command per chapter, then I have to turn that off in one place and it will be much easier to maintain also.

Here is a MWE of what I mean

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}%this is global effect

\begin{document}
\chapter{introduction} 
%\Need Command Here To turn OFF Starting Each 
%Section On New Page After The First Section 
  \section{A} 
   blabla
  \section{B} 
   blabla

\chapter{Another chapter}
%\Need Command Here To turn ON Starting Each Section On New Page
%And later on, in next chapter, I might turn it off again
  \section{A} 
   blabla
  \section{B} 
   blabla

\end{document}
```

reference [start-new-page-with-each-section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section)

btw, I use lualatex.

Comment: just put `\renewcommand\sectionbreak{}` at the start of chapters where it is disabled and redefine it back to clearpage in the others.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you. That worked very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put

```
\renewcommand\sectionbreak{}
```

at the start of chapters where it is disabled and redefine it back to `\clearpage` in the others.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an automated way to this this that only requires you to make changes in the preamble. You can use the `\SetChaptersWithPageBreaks` to give a comma separated list of the numbers of the chapters where you want page breaks between each section. For example, with

```
\SetChaptersWithPageBreaks{2,3,5}
```

chapters 2,3 and 5 will have these page breaks and the other chapters will not. With this is place the MWE below produces:

[image]

plus quite a few other pages. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_chapters_with_page_breaks_clist
\newcommand\SetChaptersWithPageBreaks[1]{
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_chapters_with_page_breaks_clist {#1}
}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{
  \clist_if_in:NxT \g_chapters_with_page_breaks_clist {\arabic{chapter}} {\clearpage}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_if_in:NnT {NxT}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% comma separated list of chapters that require page breaks afer  sections
\SetChaptersWithPageBreaks{2,3,5}

\begin{document}
\chapter{introduction}
  \section{A} blabla \section{B} blabla

\chapter{Another chapter}
  \section{A} blabla \section{B} blabla

\chapter{Another chapter}
  \section{A} blabla \section{B} blabla

\chapter{Another chapter}
  \section{A} blabla \section{B} blabla

\chapter{Another chapter}
  \section{A} blabla \section{B} blabla

\chapter{Another chapter}
  \section{A} blabla \section{B} blabla

\end{document}
```