# \clearpage in \NewTColorBox for new section

Tags: tcolorbox

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{ctexart} 
\ctexset{
    section={
        name={Week},
        number={~\arabic{section}}
    }
}%
\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancybox}  % fancybox~~~
% Graphicx
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}
%
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksopen=false,
    pdfstartview= FitH
}
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}
\tcbset{%
    colback=white,
    tikz={opacity=0.1,transparency group},
    colframe=black,
    title filled=false,
%   bookmark={Q\arabic{\tcbcounter}}
    bookmark={W\thesection\_Q\arabic{\tcbcounter}}
}
%%%%%%%% disable for publishing %%%%%%
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-1}



\NewTColorBox[
    auto counter,
    number freestyle={ W\noexpand\thesection/Q\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter} }
    ]{question}{ O{}mo }{
    lowerbox=ignored, %invisible/ignored
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=\thetcbcounter: #2,
% after title/after upper
    IfValueTF={#3}{after title={\hfill\colorbox{red}{\texttt #3}}}{},
    before = \clearpage,
    #1
}%

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%%


\section[Week \thesection]{}

\begin{question}{Tiiiiiiiiitle}[Whatever] 
lipsum[4]
\end{question}

\begin{question}{Tiiiiiiiiitle}[Whatever] 
lipsum[4]
\end{question}

\begin{question}{Tiiiiiiiiitle}[Whatever] 
lipsum[4]
\end{question}


\section[Week \thesection]{}

\begin{question}{Tiiiiiiiiitle}[Whatever] 
lipsum[4]
\end{question}

\begin{question}{Tiiiiiiiiitle}[Whatever] 
lipsum[4]
\end{question}

\begin{question}{Tiiiiiiiiitle}[Whatever] 
lipsum[4]
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Notice how the `\clearpage` did not work on page 3 for the new section?
Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: It works like in first box. It's the `\section` command which avoid the effect of `\clearpage`. Why? I don't know. But if you introduce some text before first section you will see how the text, section title and first box remain on same page. Just like it happens with fourth box where third box, section title and fourth box remain on page.

Comment: So is there a way to make it work without adding any text? What I want is basically make each TBOX to start on a new page.

Comment: As the problem is with `\section`, you should find how to force `section` to start a new page. Something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9497/1952)

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks. Problem solved.