# How to start each section of the appendix on a new page

Tags: spacing, appendices, appendix

I am writing a a latex article of the documentclass `article`. It has several appendices. I would like to have each of the sections in my appendix, to begin on a new page, i.e. new sections titles should be at the top of the page. How do I do that without adding a `\newpage` manually before every `\section` command.

Note I do not want this behavior for the sections in the main body of the article.

Note that this similar question: [Start new page with each section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section) asks for placing ***every*** section title at the top of the page. I, on the other hand, want this behavior only for appendix sections.

Comment: `\usepackage{etoolbox}\apptocmd\appendix{\pretocmd\section{\clearpage}{}{}}{}{}` will change the definition of `\section` to issue a `\clearpage` after you used `\appendix` in your document.

Comment: Of course, the easy solution is just to add a \clearpage where needed.