# Start sections on a new page, excepting the first one

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

So, I've seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section#9505), but I need sections to start on a new page only after the first one

And I've been trying many different methods, and I was thinking that I could make an if statement somewhere that if the section number exceeds 2, it'll begin adding a `\clearpage`. But I need this if statement to run with each new section that gets created, in theory

My major attempt at this was to do it inside my already-exsiting `\titleformat` command, since I thought that it'll run the `if` with each new section, and it looked something like this:

```tex
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{} % create it empty at first to modify later
\titleformat{\section}
{\large\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{0pt}
{
\ifnum\value{section} > 1
{\renewcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}}
\else{\renewcommand{\sectionbreak}{}}
\fi
}
{}
```

I thought it'll run the `if` after each section, because, in another document, I have another `\ifnum` statement similar to this one that makes a `\hspace` smaller in the separator, if the section number is larger than 10

But, this doesn't work, and I don't know what else to try. So, any solutions? This is going to be something used in both a `book`, and also in an `article` documentclass. So, class isn't very relevant

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE beginning with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}`, and including only such packages as might be relevant here (stuff like `titlesec` if you are using it...)? I'm assuming the `\documentclass` is one that has *chapters* in addition to sections (so not `article`...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define `\sectionbreak` properly:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\ifnum\value{section}>0 \clearpage\fi}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{One:}

\section{on same page}

Some text

\section{On new page}

Some text

\section{On new page}

Some text

\chapter{Two:}

\section{on same page}

Some text

\section{On new page}

Some text

\section{On new page}

Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This solution adapts your already promising approach with `\ifnum`.

However, I found (in a MWE I made) that placing the conditional code in the 5th argument of `\titleformat`, as you did, messes with the section headers. I.e., the desired page break is placed *between* section number and title. The 5th argument, officially `before-code`, is executed ["before the title body"](https://mirror.informatik.hs-fulda.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf#page=4) but apparently *after* the section number.

My favoured approach in these cases would be with the `\preto` macro from `etoolbox`, because the conditional then becomes active *right before* the *entire* workings of `\section`.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\section{\ifnum\value{section}=0
\else\clearpage\fi}
```

Assuming you are working with a document class that has chapters in addition to sections (say `book`), and that the "first" section refers to the first section *in each chapter*, this would be a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\large\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{0pt}
{}
{}

\preto\section{\ifnum\value{section}=0
\else\clearpage\fi}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One:}

\section{on same page}

\section{On new page}

\section{On new page}

\chapter{Two:}

\section{on same page}

\section{On new page}

\section{On new page}

\end{document}
```

[image: table of contents with page numbers]

Comment: I am going to use this method, I found another way to do what I was asking for, by replacing the `\sectionbreak` command renewals with the code snippet that got accepted as an answer inside the question I mentioned (this: `\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\clearpage}`). I'm going to use your method though, because I noticed mine messes with section headers as you mentioned, adding some extra space.

Comment: @Andy3153 Thanks for accepting :) Right, now I've seen the other answer in your linked question. To be fair, the method with the hook is even simpler and more organic than mine (if your LaTeX distribution is reasonably new)

Comment: @Andy3153 Still, for future reference, could you please edit your question to say which document class you are using?

Comment: Well, the thing is, this was going to be something used in both a `book`, and also in an `article` documentclass. So, class isn't very relevant. Should I add anything in this case?

Comment: I see! Maybe you could add what you just wrote, it's certainly helpful to know!

Comment: @Andy3153 Actually [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/639584/203961) should be the accepted one. Do feel free to un-accept mine :). And follow @egreg's advice as it's the intended way to use `titlesec`!