# How to add newpage at each subsection

Tags: formatting

How do I automatically set a \newpage at each \subsection ? I'm using article mode.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! [Start new page with each section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section), change section into subsection will do. That would mean `\AddToHook{cmd/subsection/before}{\clearpage}` in the preamble.

Comment: just subsection, not also section?